# Using awk to print index of a pattern in a file

Tags: awk

I've been sitting on this one for quite a while:

I would like to search for a pattern in a `sample.file` using awk and print the index:

```
>sample
ATGCGAAAAGATGAACGA
GTGACAGACAGACAGACA
GATAAACTGACGATAAAA
...
```

Let's say I want to find the index of the following pattern: "AAAA" (occurs twice), so the result should be 6 and 51.

**EDIT:**

I was able to use the following script:

```
cat ./sample.fasta |\
awk '{
    s=$0
    o=0
    m="AAAA"
    l=length(m)
    i=index(s,m)
    while (i>0) {
        o+=i
        print o
        s=substr(s,i+l)
        o+=l-1
        i=index(s,m)
    }
}'
```

However, it restarts the index on every new line, so the result is 6 and 15. I can always concatenate all lines into one single line, but maybe there's a more elegant way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you've put up now was written for the case where you're only searching a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` reads files line-by-line so it would never be a problem to find "all" indices in a multi-line file. Your problem is that you're trying to use a `BEGIN` block which, as its name suggests, only runs at the beginning of the program. As well, the `index()` function takes two arguments.

For your sample data, this should work:

```
awk '/AAAA/{print index($0,"AAAA")+l} NR>1{l+=length}' sample.file
```

The first block of code only runs when `AAAA` is matched, the second runs for every line after the first, incrementing the counter with the length of the line.

---

For the case where you have multiple matches per line, this should work:

```
awk -v pat=AAAA 'BEGIN{for(n=0;n<length(pat);n++) rep=rep"x"} NR>1{while(i=index($0,pat)){print i+l; sub(pat,rep);} l+=length}' sample.file
```

The pattern is passed as a variable; when the program starts a replacement text is generated based on the length of the pattern. Then each line after the first is looped over, getting the index of the pattern and replacing it so the next iteration returns the next instance.

It's worth mentioning that both these methods will match `AAAAAA`.

Comment: Works nicely. Although I don't need it now, I was wondering how you would match exactly "AAAA" without find AAAAAs patterns?

Comment: You'd just use a pattern like `[^A]AAAA[^A]` and rework the code to accept a regex search instead of a string search. (`index()` can't search for regular expressions.)

Comment: Just updated it to skip the first line, I didn't realize it was part of the data.

Answer (score 1):

AWK indexes of course:

```
awk '{ l=index($0, "AAAA"); if (l) print l+i; i+=length(); }' dna.txt
```

```
6
51
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, however I had to add sed 1d dna.txt | awk '{your code}' in order to ignore characters from the header on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

if you're fine with zero based indices, this may be simpler.

```
$ sed 1d file | tr -d '\n' | grep -ob AAAA

5:AAAA
50:AAAA
```

assumes you have the header row as posted, if not remove `sed` command.  Note that this assumes single byte chars as shown.  For extended charsets it won't be the char position but byte-offset.

Comment: `sed 1d sample.fasta | tr -d '\n' | grep -ob AAAA` then I get
`0:AAAA
AAAA`

Something's wrong, however I used your `sed` part in the above comments to make them work. Thanks!

Comment: `| awk -F: '{print $1+1}'`